# Unnecessary Recomposition of Composables when Changing TextField Value in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I'm working on an application using Jetpack Compose, and I've encountered an issue that's puzzling me. Every time I change the value of a TextField, all composables in my user interface are recomposed, even those not directly related to the TextField.

```
@Composable
fun Test(
    viewModel: TestViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state = viewModel.state

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        TextField(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), value = state.address, onValueChange = {
            viewModel.updateAddress(it)
        })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
        TextField(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), value = state.address2, onValueChange = {
            viewModel.updateAddress2(it)
        })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
        TextField(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), value = state.address3, onValueChange = {
            viewModel.updateAddress3(it)
        })
    }

}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class TestViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    var state by mutableStateOf(TestState())
        private set

    fun updateAddress(address: String) {
        state = state.copy(
            address = address
        )
    }

    fun updateAddress2(address: String) {
        state = state.copy(
            address2 = address
        )
    }

    fun updateAddress3(address: String) {
        state = state.copy(
            address3 = address
        )
    }
}


data class TestState(
    val address: String = "",
    val address2: String = "",
    val address3: String = "",
)
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsSEj.png)

[Layout Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTMif.png)

I suspect that the issue may be related to the following code snippet:

```
state = state.copy(
    address = address
)
```

What would be the best solution for a large project?

I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The inspector is showing these function as recomposing as all but one of the `TextField`s is being called with the same parameters it will be skipped and will return immediately.

You can verify this in the debugger by stepping into `TextField` for the versions that are not changing and validate that function just checks the parameters you passed are the same as last time and then returns.